# Suggestions on Improving Solr Indexing Speed

Tags: solr, indexing

Please let me know if you need any more information from my side.

I am new to Solr and Solr Indexing. I have 2 Million Records to be indexed and adding more soon, it is taking 16 hours to complete the index now for 2 Million Records.

Can you please provide Suggestions and helpful links on Improving the Indexing Speed.

Comment: Have you considered using multiple indexes? For example, instead of using just sitecore_web_index you can break it out into one for each of your websites.

Comment: Need lots more information here. By 2 million records, do you mean 2 million Sitecore items? Does it take 16 hours to rebuild the default indexes like sitecore_master_index? Do you have any modifications to those indexes? Is this a local Solr installation or something externally hosted?

Comment: Are you also indexing media files?  I've noticed indexing media adds considerable time to indexing speeds.  I would definitely look at Sharding if you can.  That will increase throughput and performance.  If you are using later versions of sitecore, consider SOLR Cloud.

Answer (score 5):

Some of the steps that can be followed to increase the performance of Solr indexing are:

1. **Limit the items getting into Solr**: You can limit the number of items that are getting indexed by changing the `<Root>/sitecore</Root>` parameter in Sitecore index configuration file.
2. **Stored Vs Indexed**: Not all fields needs to be both Stored as well as indexed. Some items just needs to be indexed but won't be stored thereby reducing the documents going into Solr. More on this here: [Stored vs Indexed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287584/solr-index-vs-stored)
3. **Check the JVM memory consumption**: As you mentioned that there are more than 2million records, there is a good chance that the current JVM Memory setting isn't sufficient and there maybe a case to increase it.
4. **Increasing Server Configuration**: You can increase the Server RAM and cores to boost the performance.
5. **Upgrading Solr itself**: Depending on the Sitecore version you are using, if there is an upgrade in scope, you can also upgrade Solr to achieve the better performance.